# Multiple outputs with ffmpeg using Constant Rate Factor

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to generate 3 video outputs of my source with high/mid/low bitrate.
Here is what I'm trying out right now:

> ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vcodec libx265 -crf 30 index_0.mp4 -crf 26 index_1.mp4 -crf 20 index_2.mp4

It seems to compute without problems, and generates 3 files with appropriate sizes. Only problem is that **index_0.mp4** (the lowest bitrate) seems to be invalid or corrupted. VLC can play it correctly, but my OS doesn't generate a preview for it and my html5 player wont play that file - the audio is there but with black picture.

Update:

If I change the order like this -

> ffmpeg -i example.mp4 -vcodec libx265 -crf 20 index_0.mp4 -crf 25 index_1.mp4 -crf 30 index_2.mp4

Then still **index_0** (this time the largest file) is corrupted

Comment: Output is not corrupted - HTML5 does not support H265. `-c:v libx265` in your command only applies to the first output. The two other outputs don't have a codec specified so they default to libx264.

Comment: yes this was the case. I tried x264 on all of them and it worked.